# SVN Update at Server side using ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, svn, tortoisesvn

I have created one batch file to run SVN update through ASP.Net web application. 
It is working fine at my computer and it updated all folders. But when I deploy it and run the same batch at server side through page, it is not been updated.

Point to note is, I am able to execute the same batch at server side manually.

Here is my batch files content..

```
/----------------------------

@echo off

set SOURCE=my source path to update
set SVN=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\

"%SVN%\svn.exe" cleanup %SOURCE%

"%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update /path:"%SOURCE%" /closeonend:1

set SOURCE=
set SVN=

/----------------------------
```

Please help out.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the user under which IIS process runs (W3P.exe) has the same rights as when you run it manually.

Comment: yeah..its the same admin user